How to rewire this dual-voltage AC motor?
I have a saw from an estate sale that has a 240V plug on it, but my shop doesn't have 240.  Only 120.  I have a 120V 20A plug, the outlet is indeed rated for 20A with 12AWG wire and a 20A breaker, and the dataplate on the motor says I can change it over, so all should be well:

But what I see inside doesn't appear to match the diagram:



The external wire colors connect to the correct labels for 230V (I'm replacing that wire too, because the insulation is all hard and crumbly), so I'm pretty sure it would run as-is (except for the bad insulation) if I just gave it 240.
The diagram does not include the starting capacitor and its cut-out relay on T5, but that's fine.  What's tripping me up though, is the jumper labelled T3 between the red and yellow motor wires.  Presumably, either red or yellow is T3 and the other is T2, and it doesn't matter which is which for 230V because they're connected anyway.  But I need to separate them for 115V and keep them straight.
Is there a standard for which is which?  And for which one goes on the relay coil?  (I assume that's what that screw terminal is?)
The starting capacitor is rated for 125V, and the relay is normally closed, as is the "manual thermal protector" between P1, P2, and the white motor wire.
Here's the dataplate again, so you don't have to scroll so much:

Measured DC resistances (rough estimates of winding length?):
Pos Neg Ohms
P1  T5* 9.6
P1  T3  1.1
P1  T4  2.1
T3  T4  1.4
T5* T3  8.7
T5* T4  9.7

*T5 is actually measured from the relay screw terminal, since the capacitor is open-circuit at DC

Welp, a bit of googling that model number got me a PDF manual for a slightly different model, but it includes a much better schematic than what's on the cover plate, and it does seem to line up:
http://www.vintagemachinery.org/pubs/1141/3731.pdf
Pages 20 and 21.
It's still a bit messy, so I redrew it in KiCad:

THAT makes sense!
I still don't understand all of the design decisions here (see Why is this AC motor wired like this?), but it does look like it ought to work.  Either way, each winding gets 115V and the correct polarity.

Welp, a bit of googling That was some fast googling! You answered your own question less than a minute later.

@Colin I decided to do that before I posted the question, in case it was embarrassingly obvious.  It wasn't THAT obvious, but I did get the answer, and I still had the almost finished question.  So I used the "Answer your own question" box, which ends up posting both simultaneously.  Maybe it's useful to someone else too.
